# A partial recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

What is the closed form solution to the following partial recurrence relation?
$$
q(n,m) = \frac{q(n-1,m-1)}{n} - q(n-1,m)
$$
where $q(0,m)=0$ for all $m > 0$ and $q(n,0) = (-1)^n$ for all $n \geq 0$.  We make the assumption that $q(n,m) = 0$ if any index is negative.  What methods are involved in finding a closed form solution?

Comment: This function needs a base case for $q(1,0)$. There's no unique way to get more values out of it as is.

Comment: @Kevin: On the not uncommon understanding that $q(n,m)=0$ when at least one index is negative, $q(n,0)=0$ for $n>0$. Failing some such assumption, you need $q(n,0)$ for **all** $n>0$.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Brian.  I should have been more clear.  As Brian suggests, I'm assuming that $q(n,m) = 0$ if any index is negative.  However, this makes $q(n,0) = (-1)^n$ for all $n > 0$.  I've added this to the question just to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to clean things up a bit first. Your recurrence can be rid of denominators and negative numbers by putting
$$
  q'(n,m)=(-1)^{n-m}n!\,q(n,m)
$$
for which the recurrence becomes
$$
  q'(n,m)=q'(n-1,m-1)+nq'(n-1,m)\quad\text{for }n,m>0
$$
with initial values
$$
  q'(n,0)=n!\qquad\text{and}\qquad q'(0,m)=0^m\qquad\text{for }n,m\geq0.
$$
Now by inspection of the recurrence or by computing a few values one sees that
$$
  q'(n,m)=\genfrac[]0{}{n+1}{m+1},\qquad\text{for }n,m\geq0
$$
where the RHS denotes an unsigned [Stirling number of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Your original equation then has as solution
$$
  q(n,m)=\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{n!}\genfrac[]0{}{n+1}{m+1},
$$
involving the signed version of the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: I see. It appears that computing the Stirling numbers involves a recursion.  So, in some sense, there isn't a closed form solution at all!

Comment: @RobbyMcKilliam: Indeed, but at least we find ourselves in good company not having found a "closed" form (say one involving polynomial expressions, factorials, without varying length summations or products).

Answer (score 2):

It also turns out that these numbers are very closely related to the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, though I discovered this empirically and only then proved it.

Here’s a table of the first few values of $q(n,m)$:

$$\begin{array}{c|r|r}
n\backslash m&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\ \hline
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&-1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
2&1&-\frac32&\frac12&0&0&0&0\\
3&-1&2&-\frac54&\frac14&0&0&0\\
4&1&-\frac52&\frac94&-\frac78&\frac18&0&0\\
5&-1&3&-\frac72&2&-\frac9{16}&\frac1{16}&0\\
6&1&-\frac72&5&-\frac{15}4&\frac{25}{16}&-\frac{11}{32}&\frac1{32}
\end{array}$$

And here is $2^{n-1}q(n,m)$:

$$\begin{array}{c|r|r}
n\backslash m&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\ \hline
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&-1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
2&2&-3&1&0&0&0&0\\
3&-4&8&-5&1&0&0&0\\
4&8&-20&18&-7&1&0&0\\
5&-16&48&-56&32&-9&1&0\\
6&32&-112&160&-120&50&-11&1
\end{array}$$

Now $a(n,m)=2^{n-m-1}q(n-m,m)$:

$$\begin{array}{c|r|r}
n\backslash m&0&1&2&3&4\\ \hline
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&-1&0&0&0&0\\
2&2&1&0&0&0\\
3&-4&-3&0&0&0\\
4&8&8&1&0&0&\\
5&-16&-20&-5&0&0\\
6&32&48&18&1&0\\
7&-64&-112&-56&-7&0\\
8&128&256&160&32&1\\
9&-256&-576&-432&-120&-9
\end{array}$$

Compare these values with the coefficients of the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Examples); it appears that

$$T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+k}a(n,k)x^{n-2k}\;.$$

To verify this, let $$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+k}a(n,k)x^{n-2k}\;.$$

The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind are given by the recurrence $$\begin{align*}&T_0(x)=1\\&T_1(x)=x\\&T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x),\quad n>1\;.\end{align*}$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
a(n+1,k)&=2^{n-k}q(n+1-k,k)\\\\
&=2^{n-k}\left(\frac12q(n-k,k-1)-q(n-k,k)\right)\\\\
&=2^{n-k-1}q(n-k,k-1)-2^{n-k}q(n-k,k)\\\\
&=a(n-1,k-1)-2a(n,k)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
S_{n+1}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+1+k}a(n+1,k)x^{n+1-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+1+k}\Big(a(n-1,k-1)-2a(n,k)\Big)x^{n+1-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+1+k}a(n-1,k-1)x^{n+1-2k}+2x\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+k}a(n,k)x^{n-2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n-1+k}a(n-1,k)x^{n-1-2k}+2x\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+k}a(n,k)x^{n-2k}\\
&=S_{n-1}(x)+2xS_n(x)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Clearly $S_0(x)=1$ and $S_1(x)=x$, so $S_n(x)=T_n(x)$ for $n\ge 0$. Thus, any expression for the coefficients of $T_n(x)$ gives an expression for the $q(n,m)$ via the transformation $$q(n,m)=2^{1-n}a(n+m,m)\;.$$

Comment: Interesting! I guess this connection with the Chebyshev polynomials is likely to be linked with Marc's solution using the Stirling numbers.